# How do you use widget field type signature in PDFKit in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am a little unsure how to use the signature widget field type in PDFKit. I've tried the following but with little luck:

```
let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50), forType: .widget, withProperties: nil)
annotation.widgetFieldType = .signature
annotation.widgetStringValue = "Hello"
pdfView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(annotation)
```